# disable mouse click for a while, of filter mouse clicks

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, click, mouseevent

Im using `Visual Basic 2008 Express`

Is there a way to disable mouse click for a while in `Visual Basic 2008`, I mean if mouse was clicked more than 1 time in very short time to click only once? -- I need it because my mouse became like crazy one.. when I click once it may clicks twice or more.., This is very very annoying... so until I buy another one, I'd like to filter click, to allow only one click and to block another clicks that were made in last second.

P.S : sorry about that question, but it is really annoying...

Thanks :)

Comment: Although I sympathize with your situation, this probably isn't the right place for your question.

Comment: yes maybe, but I asked about vb.net code to do this.

Comment: [Mouse keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys) to control the mouse via the keypad?

Comment: no, code to block mouse clicks, If there were more than 1 click in last second, to click only once and to block next clicks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an article on processing global mouse events on The Code Project: [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/globalhook.aspx).  It looks like the article lead to a project called [Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks .NET Libary in C#](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/).  You should be able to include the library in your VB.NET project and attach to events from there.  The article also references some other information on MSDN that you should read before embarking on this project.

This is something that would be much easier to do from an unmanaged language like C or C++ though.

*Although these samples are in C#, they should be easy enough to translate into VB.NET.*